# Minikube: Multicast from server into pods

Tags: kubernetes, networking, minikube

I have a server that is receiving **multicast messages** on a network interface called "em2".

I need to get the information coming over into my pods running in minikube so I can use it in an application which I am writing. How would I go about doing this?

The network interfaces shown in `minikube ssh` are: docker0, eth0, eth1, lo, and two "veth"

Thank you!

Comment: Which minikube [driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) are you using ? Maybe using the [none](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/) driver is what you need ?

Comment: @matt_j - I am using VirtualBox, which is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve traffic towards Kubernetes pod(s):

- Adding `hostNetwork: true` flag to the yaml file along with `hostPort` configuration in order to receive the traffic directly to the pod.
- The [multus-cni](https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) project allows the creation of additional interfaces for your pods (your default one won't accept multicast). Then you will need to bridge the new interface with the em2 interface in your host machine, either by using bridge or `macvlan`
- You could use some firewall (e.g. `iptables`, `ipfw`, `nftables`, etc.) to forward the traffic from the em2 interface to the internal K8 network

Comment: This helped steer me in the right direction. I used the `hostNetwork` but then also add in `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet`. Works great - thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help!